# use decorator with self in class

Tags: python, bottle

I am a student and I want to practice MVC and OOP with a little website with the Bottle microframework.

So my controller instantiate a Bottle object, and send it to my model. My model need to use the "route" decorator of the Bottle class to define routing (`@app.route("/blog")` for example).

But it looks like I cant use a decorator in a class because `self` dont exist outside a method.

So how can I do that in a MVC and OOP approach? ie I would like to avoid to instantiate Bottle outside a class and use it as a global variable.

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf8-*-

from bottle import Bottle, run




class Model():
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app


    @self.app.route("/hello") ### dont work because self dont exist here
    def hello(self):
        return "hello world!"


class View():
    pass


class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Bottle()
        self.model=Model(self.app)



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    run(host="localhost", port="8080", debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.hello = self.app.route("/hello")(self.hello) 

    def hello(self):
        return "hello world!"
```